# How to make overlapping background for custom shape on link hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

Example of the image:

[image]

I have 2 links: **1** and **2**
two background gradient images: **blue-green** and **yellow-red**.

After hovering on one of them (1 or 2) I want to have triangle with proper extention background.

e.g. when hovering on **1** I want to have begining of **blue-green** gradient triangle, same for **2** but proper position of gradient.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you want. Could you provide an image of the link 1 hovered and another of the link 2 hovered ?

Answer (score 1):

Making pure css shapes work by doing variously obscure things with border widths. I played around a bit trying to combine the [triangle rules](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/) with the [border gradient rules](http://css-tricks.com/examples/GradientBorder/) and couldn't get them to cooperate (in Chrome, anyways). The border image stuff works by slicing the image into 9 bits (4 corners, 4 edges and center); it always seems to override the transparent & angled edges that the hard shape border rules rely upon.

All that is to say that I don't have a solution for you, but you're probably out of luck as far as a pure css solution goes, even using CSS3. You're probably going to need some JS or image trickery to get the effect you're looking for.